How to Implement Hysteresis in a Multi-Winding Transformer in Multisim?
I’m working with multi-winding transformer models in Multisim, specifically the 1p2s model. I need to implement hysteresis in the core's characteristics. Which function should I use to achieve this, and how can I ensure that the simulation traces the hysteresis loop correctly?
I considered using a tabular method from Multisim, similar to inductance=f(current) with a table like:

table(%I, -5.1, 1u, -5, 1u, -3, 50u, 3, 50u, 5, 1u, 5.1, 1u)

If you have experience with this or any alternative suggestions, I would appreciate your input!
Thank you!

